# Does it have convergent subsequence in that form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $P_i$ be sequence of prime numbers i.e $P_1=2,P_2=3,P_3=5 ...$

Euler has proved that the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{P_i}$$ is divergent.

Set $a_i=P_{P_i}$ then $a_1=P_2=3$ , $a_2=P_{3}=5$ and $a_3=P_5=11$ ...

My question is that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a_i}$$ is convergent or not. From a more general perspextive if set $$a_i=P_{P_{P_{._{._{P_i}}}}}$$ (n times sub) then can we conclude that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a_i}$$ is convergent ? if it is so, what is the minumum of such $n$ ?

Comment: This is a dupe but I can't find it at the moment. It's convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manage to prove 
$$ p_n \geq (1-\varepsilon)\, n \log n \tag{1}$$
for a certain $\varepsilon \geq 0$, for any $n$ big enough ($n\geq n_0$), then:
$$ \sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{p_{p_n}} \leq \frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{p_n \log p_n} \leq \frac{1}{(1-\varepsilon)^2}\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n \log n\log p_n}\leq \frac{1}{(1-\varepsilon)^2}\sum_{n\geq n_0}\frac{1}{n \log^2 n}$$
is convergent since
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$$
is convergent by Cauchy's condensation test. In order to prove $(1)$, you may use the PNT or the Chebyshev's weaker version.

Comment: Or just use [Rosser's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_theorem) and see that $p_n > n\ln n$ :-)

Comment: @PeterKošinár: I wasn't aware of that result. It is really nice, it gives that we can just take $\varepsilon=0$, many thanks.